# How broad does an action have to be to be allowed to be published?

Tags: actions-on-google

Imagine I own a small dog grooming business in a small town.  Imagine my company is called "Happy Dog" (I'm making this up).  Can I write an action that could then be published as "Happy Dog" such that when a user says "Talk to Happy Dog" it will direct users to my action to find out store hours, make bookings and learn prices?

I am not asking about the technical characteristics of such an action.  I'm imagining that if I build the action and submit it to Google, they will have to enter it into their database to cause it to be triggered.  I'm assuming that this will then trigger its presence "globally".

When I look at https://assistant.google.com/explore/ ... I see nothing that would seem to show small businesses and other such actions being visible.  This *implies* to me that Google rejects such submissions.  Is it easy or difficult to get a new assistant action registered with Google?  Is there any reading material I should be studying to learn about publishing new actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, we can think of Actions being published globally (there are caveats to that - but ignoreable for your question). Despite this, Actions should be broad enough to be useful, but can certainly be of interest to only a narrow audience.

As an analogy - this is similar to how web sites are published globally. The invocation name is a rough parallel to the domain name for a web site (with the exclusion of the ".com" or whatever TLD you use). Google acts as the sole domain registrar, if we wish to extend this analogy. And while it does enforce [certain rules](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#naming_and_directory_listing) about naming and the directory entry there is no restriction specifically about local or small businesses.

However... you do start running into naming conflicts and trademark issues. For example, you probably can't get "MacDonald's" because it is too close to a trademarked name. One word invocations aren't allowed unless you can verify you also have the corresponding domain name.

To continue the analogy using your example, if you started your "Happy Dog" grooming company, you may try to create a web site and discover that "happydog.com" was already taken. So perhaps you would go with "HappyDogGrooming.com" or "HappyDogSpringfield.com" or something else. In the same way, if "talk to Happy Dog" was already taken, you may need to register "talk to Happy Dog Grooming" or something similar.

It is not difficult to get new Actions [published](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/publish), although you do need to make sure you follow the rules. The review process mostly makes sure you have created a good conversational experience that actually works and does not confuse users. Sometimes there is a bit of back-and-forth with the review team to resolve issues.